# Dynamic Colspan for td in xslt

Tags: asp.net, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have...

```
<tr>
<xsl:variable name="noofrows" select="count(ChargeGroupsVo)"></xsl:variable>
<td colspan="$noofrows" style="border-top: 1px solid black;padding: 5px;"></td>
</tr>
```

Here
**ChargeGroupsVo** is class of data having count some 8
i want that count 8 as colspan....
**output type of xslt is HTML**
How to do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did this...

```
<td>
                                                <xsl:for-each select="ChargeGroupNames">
                                                    <xsl:variable name="norows" select="count(ChargeGroupsVo)"></xsl:variable>
                                                    <xsl:if test="$norows &gt; 1">
                                                        <xsl:attribute name="colspan">
                                                            <xsl:value-of select="$norows + 2"/>
                                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                                    </xsl:if>
                                                </xsl:for-each>
</td>
```

dynamically added attribute and value....

Answer (score 3):

You need to use 'Attribute Value Templates' here.

Instead of doing this....

```
 <td colspan="$noofrows" style="border-top: 1px solid black;padding: 5px;"></td>
```

You need to do this

```
<td colspan="{$noofrows}" style="border-top: 1px solid black;padding: 5px;"></td>
```

The curly braces { } indicate it is an expression to be evaluated, rather than something to be output literally.

In fact, you don't really need the variable at all. You can do this too:

```
<td colspan="{count(ChargeGroupsVo)}" style="border-top: 1px solid black;padding: 5px;"></td>
```